# Database Build/Clean time

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages

I have noticed that lately our xpages application build/compilation time has gone drastically up. It can even take almost whole minute to clean application.

It is quite complex app with some controls (custom controls and java controls) and a lot of legacy code (js, ls, java), but similar app build in pure ecplise with the same amout of java code (which is the only part of this app that changes) cleans in less than 3 seconds ...

I have done a bit of research with rcp debug console and noticed that while cleaning there is some insane traffic that sums to 15000 transactions (and this database has only like 300 design elements that contains code at all!)

The log looks like this repeated over and over again:

...
[1240:0007-03E0] (13586-124 [14561]) OPEN_NOTE(REPC12579BB:0033C2FE-NT00003052,00400000): 0 ms. [48+17446=17494]

[1240:0007-03E0] (13587-124 [14562]) OPEN_NOTE(REPC12579BB:0033C2FE-NT00006C12,00400000): 1 ms. [48+32118=32166]

So my question is:

Does this mean that xpages builder is really badly written or maybe I do not know something?

Comment: Try doing clean /compile with a local copy of the database to see if there is a network issue.

Comment: With local copy clean time went down from 50s do 15s. Its better but doing replication each time I want test app adds too much overhead and is really annoying.

Comment: Then I would say that you have a network speed issue. I have seen this too, but I believe it has improved with 8.5.3.

Comment: Oh I have forgotten to mention - my server and designer version is 8.5.3FP1 and server is inside local virtual machine(win2008 64bit). The computer is top lenovo laptop with the best possible processor and best possible ssd disk (both worth small fortune :)) ...

Comment: My guess is that the bottleneck is the virtual network. Or if you using dns name to connect to the server, try changing to ip.

Comment: It's not just the network; something about the virtual file system Designer uses forces it to be slower if it knows it's not a local replica. Even if you're running against a server on the same machine, it's slower than against a true local replica, though not nearly as much as against a remote server. Sadly, the most efficient approach is to code against a local server... you take the minor hit on build time, but don't have to replicate for every unit test.

Comment: @W_K: If you're working on a local replica, you can use a keyboard shortcut to replicate. Alt + F + R + R + Enter. Replicate in background. It's not that bad compared to compiling the app on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its appears after all that there is a solution to build time problem - its the new Domino Designer 9. After upgrading to public beta version the build times dropped drastically (to just few seconds)!

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing Project - Build or Project - Build All. If the latter and you have multiple NSFs open, then the build will run for all apps. You can close the apps in Package Explorer.

When you say there are 300 design elements, is that the number you see in the Applications Navigator? Bear in mind that's just a drop in the ocean of the actual files being built. Package Explorer will show there are additional Java and xsp-config files for each XPage and Custom Control. These are the Java classes compiled down from the XML markup you see in the XPages and Custom Control design elements. But this is not all that gets built. The server or local database cannot run .java files. It needs to run .class files compiled for the relevant platform. In addition, there are other .class files that need incorporating into the application at compile time, which can be seen by selecting Project - Properties in the Package Explorer view. If you have localization, there are still more files for each language for each XPage / Custom Control. And of course there are files like xsp.properties, an activator .java file and .class file.

The XPage builder may seem badly written because these files need creating. But it is actually very clever, because we don't need to write Java and we don't need to define all the relevant Java files the application is dependent on. We don't need to create a new XSPInput or whatever the Java classes are for the various controls. We can just drag and drop, set the properties from pretty panels which give us drop-downs or Boolean selectors etc. Without those the build time for the app after each save would be quicker, but the development time would be slower.

Comment: I was using Project/Clean as an example so I'm sure that only one db was build. 300 was the rough estimate of elements with any kind of code - I did not included dynamicly created java and xml files beacause this is not what is the bottleneck. The real problem is the compilation of my java classes which takes 2/3 of time - its easy to prove, if I put all classes into jars the compilation time drops drastically. The localization is fortunately turned off (what a bad mechanizm it is I must say).

Comment: I forgot to point this out: The fact that xpages uses xml like language to declartively define app structure (its what allow pretty panels to work) does not have any influence on building time. The problem is the time it takes to build standard java (which I have a lot because I do not use ssjs)